# Do I need transit visa to visit Zurich if I have a valid F-1 visa?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, f1-visas, zrh

I hold an Indian passport and Indian citizenship and a valid F-1 (student) visa.

I have a 17 hours halt at Zurich on my journey from the USA to India in December.

Instead of sitting at the airport if I want to visit the city for few hours, do I need a transit visa? If yes what type of visa is required and how to apply for the same? Is there any option of on-arrival visa? Any links would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at our other questions on requiring a transit visa in Zurich for Indian citizens? We have quite a few...

Answer (score 1):

You [do not need a transit visa](https://www.bfm.admin.ch/content/dam/data/bfm/rechtsgrundlagen/weisungen/visa/bfm/bfm-anh01-liste2-e.pdf), but to enter Zurich you will need a visa.

You cannot get it on arrival, you would have to apply for it before your trip.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Kindly let me know which type of VISA do I need being an Indian Citizen and how to apply? If you could provide with any links, it is highly appreciated.